# How to use SlideDown for Child ULs using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to slide down the submenu on hover (and slideup  on mouseleave). This code isnt working. 
When I just say `$(".content").slideDown`, both the submenus slidedown, on hover over any header.

**JS:**

```
$(document).Ready(function() {

$(".header").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).find(".content").slideDown("slow");

});
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
 <ul>
   <li class="header"><a href="#">People</a>
    <ul class="content">
      <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="header"><a href="#">Animals</a>
    <ul class="content">
      <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vN44B/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".header").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".content").slideDown("slow");
 }, function () {
    $(this).find(".content").slideUp("slow");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo :

```
$(document).ready(function() { //<---No capital on ready

    $(".header").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find(".content").slideDown("slow");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You were using `$(document).Ready()` instead of instead of `$(document).ready()`.

Please find the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V6QG3/)

Additionally, it uses **`hover()`** handler of jquery

Answer (score 1):

check this fiddle : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cocoa_beans/LLTKZ/)

a css solution

```
nav > ul > li{float:left;margin:0 5px;background:#cc3333;}
.header li a{background:#eee;color:#cc3333;}
.header li a:hover{color:#fff;background:#cc3333;}
ul{padding:0;}
li{list-style-type:none;}
a{color:#fff;text-decoration:none;padding:5px;display:block;text-align:center;}
.content{display:none;}
.header:hover > .content{display:block;}
```